# TCPIP server single connection

Tags: c#, sockets

i am using c# sockets Asynchronous mode.

i need to serve only one connection in my application from a server point of view. once one is connected then i would like to refuse any more connection requests.

also the server only serves to connect to a single client. when the communication is done the server has to be restarted.

but from what i have read on the topic, it is not possible to close beginaccept.

i would like some ideas regarding how get around this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, in the `BeginAccept` async callback you would call `BeginAccept` again so that another connection can be accepted. However, you can omit this step if you do not want to allow another connection. So that the connection is refused in a timely manner, consider also closing the listening socket in the callback. The accepted `Socket` will remain open in this case for you to use even though the listening socket is closed.

```
class SocketTest
{
    private Socket m_Listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    public void Test()
    {
        m_Listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8888));
        m_Listener.Listen(16);
        m_Listener.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }

    private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket s = m_Listener.EndAccept(ar);
        m_Listener.Close();
        /* Use s here. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks for helping me understand the scope of Asynchronous  sockets.